# protobuf install failure on windows

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I tried to mvn install protobuf-v3.0.0 pre-built binaries on windows, but it prompts an error as below.

D:/Tools/protobuf-java-3.0.0/protobuf-3.0.0/java/core/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/AbstractMessage.java:[327,26]

both com.google.protobuf.Message.Builder and com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.Builder define clone() method with different return type.

environments: jdk 1.6, maven 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it was a bug in java 1.6 which was later fixed. 
[Link](https://github.com/google/protobuf/pull/2602)